# why str1 not printing properly?

Tags: arrays, c, string, c-strings

```
#include<stdio.h>
void my_strconcat(char*, char*);

int main()
{
    char s1[] = "HelloGoodMorningEveryone1";
    char s6[] = "How";
    printf("String Concatenate Start! \n");
    my_strconcat(s1, s6);
    printf("s1:%s s6:%s \n", s1, s6);
    return 0;
}
void my_strconcat(char *src, char *dest)
{    
    while(*dest)
        dest++;
    while(*src) {
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

**output:**
String Concatenate Start!
s1:elloGoodMorningEveryone1 s6:HowHelloGoodMorningEveryone1

Comment: `char s6[]` This reserves no room for the `s1` string to append, so `my_strconcat` overruns the buffer.

Comment: @dxiv rather, `s6`

Comment: @dxiv actually `s6` is the destination buffer.

Comment: Also note, most string functions are `str...(char *dest, char *src)`. So you may inject confusion swapping the order. You are free to do so, just make sure you keep things straight if you then call `strcpy()` or `strcat()` later.

Answer (score 3):

Your destination buffer does not have any space left for storing the  concatenated result. So, inside the function, you're essentially overrunning the allocated memory, creating [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate enough space to the destination buffer, like

```
 char s6[128] = "How";
```

so that it's able to store the concatenated result, before you try to store the result.